# Binomial test returns p-value = 0

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I am using [binom.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/binom.test.html) and very occasionally find results that give a p-value of `0`.

An example is:

```
binom.test(x=700, n=3000, p=0.01, alternative = "greater")$p.val
```

> x = number of successes, or a vector of length 2 giving the numbers of successes and failures, respectively
>   n = number of trials; ignored if x has length 2
>   p = hypothesized probability of success

What can I do here? Is this an expected result?

Comment: I'd say zero is a pretty good estimate of your chance of getting 700 successes out of 3000 if you are only expecting 30!

Comment: Rounding? If you look at the full output, that is, `binom.test(x=700, n=3000, p=0.01, alternative = "greater")` the p value is actually `p-value < 2.2e-16`.

Comment: As @AndrewGustar is alluding to, I think the "real" probability is different from zero by a magnitude that is considerably smaller than what you can expect to calculate without quite some effort to get around floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: @joran - That is what I thought. This is a bit of a problem for reporting and plotting p-values though. How can I dig out the `2.2e-16` from the output?

Comment: It's not really in the returned object, that `< 2.2e-16` is happening in the print method, for display. i.e. it's seeing a p value of exactly zero and (correctly) inferring that all we can say is that the value is less than the numerical precision we're capable of. It's actually created by a format function called `format.pval` called from within `print.htest`.

Comment: Somewhat unsolicited advice, but in reporting terms its probably safer to report whether or not the p-value is exceeding the threshold you are using for statistical significance e.g. p-value < .01 if testing at 99% level, or to report values rounded to 3/4 digits. When expressing numbers on the order of 2.2e-16 you need so many digits that you are surely not being precise (how many digits in the calculation do we think are significant?).

Comment: @gfgm - that's true but the issue still stands for plotting such data